# Find all primes $(p, q)$ such that $p^3 - q^5 = (p+q)^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

After rearranging I got that,
$p^2(p-1)=q(q^4+q+2p)$ and clearly $p>q$
So, $q|p-1$
Thus, $p-1=kq$ where $k$ is any integer
Now putting it in the original equation,I get that
$$k^3q^2+2k^2q+k-q^4-2kq-q-2=0$$
But now I don't know how to proceed from here...please give me some hints or correct me if I am wrong

I am so sorry for my terrible mistake....it would be $q^5$ instead of $q^2$ .....really sorry(although i got some really good answers)

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  In order for MathJax commands to be effective, they must be enclosed in`$` signs.  For example, `$x^2$` shows up as $x^2$.

Comment: How do you get a term in $q^5$ (or reduced to $q^4$) when the original equation is quadratic in $q$?

Comment: There's something wrong.  Where does $q^4$ come from?

Comment: Why not just expand to get $p^3=p^2+2pq+q^2-q^2=p^2+2pq$?

Comment: @Lulu You have a sign wrong in the $q^2$ term, I think.

Comment: @MarkBennet  Oh, absolutely.  Thanks.

Comment: General positive integer solutions are: $$p=2 n^2 - 2 n + 1, \\q=(2 n^2 - 2 n + 1) (n - 1)$$ Then, we need to take $n=2$.

Comment: For anybody interested, a fairly similar question is [Diophantine equation involving prime numbers : $p^3 - q^5 = (p+q)^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/474768/602049).

Answer (score 3):

$p^3 - q^2 = p^2+2pq + q^2$ so $p^3-p^2=2q^2+2pq$ so $p^2(p-1)=2q(q+p)$

So $p|2q(q+p)$ but $p$ is prime so either $p|2$ and $p=2$ or $p|q$ and $p = q$ or $p|q+p$ and so $p|q$ and $p = q$.

So either $p = 2$ or $p = q$.

If $p = 2$ we have $4 = 2q(q+2)$ so $2=q(q+2)$ but that equation has no integer solutions.

So $p = q$ and we have

$p^2(p-1) = 2p(p+p) = 4p^2$  so $p-1 = 4$ and $p = q = 5$ and $5^3 - 5^2 = (5+5)^2$ is the only solution.

Of course, everyone else made one calculation error or another so I probably did too.

Comment: Well, how did you go from $4 = 2q(q+2)$ to $q=0$?  You got the right answer, though.

Comment: Oops.... I did in my head that $2q(q+2) = 2q^2 + 4$ and so $4= 2q^2 + 4$ and $0 = 2q^2$.  I'll fix that.

Answer (score 0):

$$p^3 - q^2 = (p+q)^2 \Rightarrow p^3-p^2-2pq = 2q^2 \Rightarrow p |2q^2$$

Since $p$ is prime we get that either $p=2$ or $p|q$.

If $p=2$ the equation becomes
$$
8-q^2=(2+q)^2 \Rightarrow q^2+(2+q)^2=8  
$$
which gives $2q^2 < 8$ and hence $q<2$ not possible.

If $p|q$ then since $q$ is prime we get $p=q$ and hence
$$
p^3=p^2+4p^2 \Rightarrow p=5 
$$

Thus $p=q=5$.

Answer (score 0):

We have,

$$\begin{align}&(p+q)^2-p^3+q^2=0 \\&2q^2+2pq+(p^2-p^3)=0\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}\Delta&=p^2-2(p^2-p^3)\\
&=p^2(2p-1)\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}&2p-1=(2n-1)^2\\
&\implies p=2n^2-2n+1\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}q&=\frac{-p+\sqrt {\Delta}}{2}\\
&=(2 n^2 - 2 n + 1) (n - 1)\end{align}$$

Thus we deduce $n=2$. This means,

$$q=5,~ p=5$$

Comment: General positive integer solutions are: $$p=2 n^2 - 2 n + 1, \\q=(2 n^2 - 2 n + 1) (n - 1)$$